# Security error in IE11 when using canvas.toDataURL('image/png')

Tags: javascript, linux, internet-explorer

I've had this code in my app for a while without any issues:

```
    var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'capture.php',
      datatype: 'json',
      data:{photo:imgData,
            IND: INDID},
      async: false,
      success: function(data){
        alert('Image saved');
      }
    });
```

Suddenly when I try this it throws a SecurityError in the first line. I did some research and found out that this is a CORS problem. I tried many suggestions but none would work.

Usually searching on the web yields an answer. On this one I am at a loss.

The server environment is Linux Ubuntu with apache2. The code is in javascript.

I tried the .htaccess suggestions but apache did not like that. My guess is that something has changed in the environment but I can't think of anything. Haven't made any updates or changes in a very long time.

Comment: It can be possible that someone changed the settings in your IE browser. Try to go to tools-> Internet options->security-> custom level-> Access data sources across domains and Enable it. https://i.postimg.cc/fR6vyCMZ/144.png

Comment: Tried that. Did not work. Additionally I'd have to make user all the users did the same. I really need a programmatic solution I can implement

Comment: Did you test the issue on any other machine with IE 11? If yes, Is same error occur on that machine too? because it can also be possible that issue is machine specific.

Comment: I did test on other machines, for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: what's the testing result? Can you provide a sample with which we can run in IE on our side to check the result may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: More details. The picture is captured with JavaScript on the client machine. Then it is saved to the server. So it appears that the cross origin is related the JavaScript code.

Comment: We cannot produce the issue with the sample you had posted in the original post. If you post the example which can produce the issue than it can give the more idea about the actual issue.

Comment: I finally found the correct code sequence:

 var imgData = document.createElement("img");;

 imgData.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
   
 imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); 

Thanks for all your efforts

Comment: System will not allow me to post answers.

Comment: May be because the new users need gain more than 50 points to post the answer in any thread.